# Apache not showing PHP Pages correctly

Tags: apache2, php

Initially the problem was PHP files on my server were displayed as plain text(the whole code was shown). So I found out by investigating that the MIME type has to be added to the `/etc/mime.types` , so I did that and also restarted my server but that didn't help solve the issue so on further investigation, I found out from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/393339/apache-shows-html-php-files-as-txt) that we needed php5 module enabled and on running the `apachectl -M`, I couldn't find the php5 module listed. So I tried installing it and this was the outcome of it :

```
admin@vm:~$ sudo apt-get install php5
...
php5_invoke pdo: already enabled for apache2 SAPI
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

admin@vm:~$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also need to mention that I created 2 virtual hosts for the sites. I am not sure what is wrong. Could some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mod_php module could not be installed. This is actually a problem on the package manager level not Apache yet.

There is unfortunately no error in your post that is helpful - maybe replace the ... with the full error message.

Some things you could try (most should be okay, but pay attention to the command output)

`$ sudo apt-get update # refresh packages 
$ sudo apt-get -f install # retry configuring packages 
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # upgrade all packages to latest version`

I guess most of these hints won't help to resolve the problem. I guess it's either permissions or manual edits of config files that break it here.

*Make a backup!* And try to start from scratch if nothing helps:

`$ sudo apt-get --purge apache2 
$ sudo apt-get --purge php5 libapache2-mod-php5 
$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove # could remove more stuff, pay attention! 
$ sudo mv /etc/apache2 /tmp/apache2.orig 
$ sudo mv /etc/php5 /tmp/php5.org 
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5 
$ sudo a2enmod php5 # enable php module`

Comment: I created a virtual host on my server could that be a cause of it being broken?

Comment: I don't think so - usally these files are in /etc/apache2/sites-available and a broken Apache config should not fail dpkg - however you could try running sudo apache2ctl configest if it's complaining.

Comment: Check out the great Debian Handbook on Apache for the quirks in Debian/Ubuntu: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.http-web-server.html

Comment: Ur second part of commands solved it! Thanks! :) Also could you help me enable short open tags too? I tried changing stuff in /etc/php/cli/php.ini but that didn't work.

Comment: putting `short_open_tag = On` at the end of `php.ini` in `/etc/php/apache2/php.ini` oder better in a seperate file in `conf.d` does not work?

Maybe it's already in the `php.ini` and set to `Off`?

Comment: I added new line at end of php.ini and that doesnt work. In the php.ini i can see `; short open tag` default value: on production value: off and development value: off.